# Consecutive Powershell scripts fail in bamboo plan

Tags: powershell, bamboo

I have a bamboo job which has the following task setup:

Task 1- Clean working directory

Task 2- checkout

Task 3- Scripts task with Inline power shell commands << runs fine every time

Task 4- some other task

Task5- Scripts task with Inline power shell commands << fails all the time, even with Write-Host “Hello”

By fails I mean in the agent log I see:
Failing task since return code of [powershell -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy bypass -Command xxxx.ps1] was-1 while expected 0
Process exception:
Power shell could not be started

I am assuming, it’s something with the powershell task instance remaining open after the first powershell task. And hence the second time it cannot get to run a second task

Is there anyway we can close this first instance??

Comment: elaborate "fails"

Comment: @Tomalak- updated

Comment: SO rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)